# Using a hosted button with quantities for options

Tags: paypal

I would like to use Paypal in conjunction with a web form for selling conference tickets.  Tickets will be available in various types and prices - standard, student, couple.

I would like users to be able to select a variety of tickets in one transaction - for example, two standard tickets and one student ticket.

Ideally I would have Paypal manage the inventory so that people can't make payments when tickets have run out.  The limit on tickets is on the total; numbers within categories don't matter.

I can set up a ticket item on Paypal and limit it to the appropriate number, and I can set option prices.  What I can't work out is how I send a request to Paypal with more than one "option + quantity" pair selected.

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not be able to send more than one option + quantity pair over to PayPal with the standard add to cart or buy now buttons and have PayPal keep track of the inventory.  Your best options would be either to set up the inventory on the PayPal side, and use add to cart buttons for each option + quantity.

Another option would be to use the cart upload method, where you pass over all the item details during checkout.  This is similar to what 3rd party carts do.  They keep track of what the buyer is adding to their cart, and then when they are ready to checkout they simply send all of the details over to PayPal in one POST.  With this method, you would have to keep track of the inventory on your end though.